# sudo apt-get update shows this messages...Unit packagekit.service not found

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, update-manager, docker

```
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Unit sysinit.target not found.
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.4.25  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.4.25  InRelease [1,572 B]
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                             
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,484 B]           
Hit:4 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease                
Hit:5 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease                                  
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Hit:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Fetched 1,484 B in 2s (811 B/s)
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit packagekit.service not found.
Reading package lists... Done
```

What do I have to do for this?... I have no idea

P.S. I was trying to run a Docker and it was not starting with:

```
sudo service docker start
"Failed to start docker.service: Unit sysinit.target not found."
```

this message...

- *this is a SSH server*

Comment: You have installed an old package. Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429895/cannot-install-cudnn-8-5-0-96-on-ubuntu-22-04-shows-the-public-cuda-gpg-key-do

Comment: its a SSH server